# New column showing the column name with largest value in a given row in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that records the exam score of 4 students `S1,S2,S3,S4` and it  looks like

```
S1        S2             S3              S4  
2         4              1               3     
1         2              3               4
3         NaN            1               2
```

And I want to create a new column called `BestStudent` which is the name of the student with the highest score in that row, so the desired outcome looks like

```
S1        S2             S3              S4         BestStudent
2         4              1               3          S2
1         2              3               4          S4
3         NaN            1               2          S1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `df['BestStudent'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)`.

Comment: explanation of what `idxmax` is doing `df.columns[df.to_numpy().argmax(1)]`

Comment: @PaulS That's a simple and elegant solution, thanks!